# How I can join my 14 pages of json into a unique file?

Tags: python, json, api, url, request

I have this code below requesting an API. I need that my code loops for every url (pagination) and save every page into my file1.json.

```
mport math
import json
import requests

url = 'https://####.zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_metrics'
user = '######'
pwd = '#######'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))

if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problema com o request. Saindo...')
    exit()

data = response.json()
valor_arredondado = math.ceil(data['count']/100)+1

for x in range(valor_arredondado):
    if x == 0: continue
    print(f"https://volvo.zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_metrics.json?page={x}")

with open("file1.json", "w") as file: 
  json.dump(data,file, indent = 4)
```

My first page starts in the page 1.  I have to go to the 14 pages I have and save my json into a unique file.

```
{
            "url": "https://#####.zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_metrics/12080264118413.json",
            "id": 12080264118413,
            "ticket_id": 119941,
            "created_at": "2023-01-09T11:30:39Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-01-10T23:01:30Z",
            "group_stations": 1,
            "assignee_stations": 1,
            "reopens": 0,
            "replies": 0,
            "assignee_updated_at": "2023-01-09T16:36:33Z",
            "requester_updated_at": "2023-01-09T11:30:39Z",
            "status_updated_at": "2023-01-12T00:01:43Z",
            "initially_assigned_at": "2023-01-09T11:30:39Z",
            "assigned_at": "2023-01-09T11:30:39Z",
            "solved_at": "2023-01-10T23:01:30Z",
            "latest_comment_added_at": "2023-01-09T16:36:33Z",
            "reply_time_in_minutes": {
                "calendar": null,
                "business": null
            },
            "first_resolution_time_in_minutes": {
                "calendar": 2131,
                "business": 1169
            },
            "full_resolution_time_in_minutes": {
                "calendar": 2131,
                "business": 1169
            },
            "agent_wait_time_in_minutes": {
                "calendar": 1825,
                "business": 863
            },
            "requester_wait_time_in_minutes": {
                "calendar": 306,
                "business": 306
            },
            "on_hold_time_in_minutes": {
                "calendar": 0,
                "business": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "next_page": "https://####.zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_metrics.json?page=2",
    "previous_page": null,
    "count": 1339
}
```

I have this code below requesting an API. I need that my code loops for every url (pagination) and save every page into my file1.json.

Comment: your initial request (and every valid page after) includes a field `next_page`. If you make a request and that field has a value it almost certainly points you to the next page of results. As you read results, you want to `extend()` them into a list you initialize as empty

Comment: What exactly should the output file look like? Does it need to be valid JSON, or does it only need to store the results from each request? When you look at the output file, how should it show you, which part came from what request?